# Search is not working for callback_column function in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have one table users in this i store 1 for website and 2 for domain and i display this table my code is,

```
    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('users');
    $crud->callback_column('listing_type',array($this,'type_change'));
    $output = $crud->render();
    return $output;
```

and my callback_column function,

```
    public function type_change($value, $row)
    {
         if($value == 1)
         {
            return 'Website';
         }
         if($value == 2)
         {
            return 'Domain Name';
         }
    }
```

so,for this search is not working for listing type if anyone have solution for this please help me , thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think that the search actually does work, but only for the values before they are processed by the callback function. So, in my fields, I have to search for `0` or `1`, instead of `No` or `Yes`. Definitely, think it is a bug in the GC core.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme use ex: `datatables` the search is client-side on visible data.

**Attention:** This solutions maybe not be good for a big number of row.